# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. Other solutions not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a react app which gets data from firebase's firestore and firebase auth. When I go to the groups page it loads perfectly fine, however when I refresh it, I get this error. If this user is not signed in it should take the user to the login page, but when I refresh, for some reason it takes to the login page even when I am signed in.

I'm getting the error `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`
I have also gotten these messages in the error
 `(anonymous)   @   Groups.js:26`
`(anonymous)  @   Groups.js:23`
I have looked at other solutions, but none of them are working.
Here is the useEffect and useState (Groups.js)

```
const [userInfo, setInfo] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [hasPassword, setHasPassword] = useState(false)
  const [groupInfo, setGroupInfo] = useState({groupName: "", groupPassword: ""})
  const [message, setMessage] = useState()

  const history = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    // Checking if user is signed in
    if (!auth.currentUser) {
      history.push("/login")
    }

    // Getting user info
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      db.collection("things").doc(user.email).get()
      .then((doc) => {
        let groups = doc.data().groups.length > 0 ? doc.data().groups : undefined
        setInfo({username: user.displayName, email: user.email, groups: groups})
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage(error.message)
      })
    })
  }, [])
```

And here is the full code (Group.js)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { db, auth } from "../firebase"
import Navbar from "./Navbar"

function Groups() {
  const [userInfo, setInfo] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [hasPassword, setHasPassword] = useState(false)
  const [groupInfo, setGroupInfo] = useState({groupName: "", groupPassword: ""})
  const [message, setMessage] = useState()

  const history = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    // Checking if user is signed in
    if (!auth.currentUser) {
      history.push("/login")
    }

    // Getting user info
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      db.collection("things").doc(user.email).get()
      .then((doc) => {
        let groups = doc.data().groups.length > 0 ? doc.data().groups : undefined
        setInfo({username: user.displayName, email: user.email, groups: groups})
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage(error.message)
      })
    })
  }, [])

  const changeHasPassword = () => {
    setHasPassword(!hasPassword)
  }

  const changeGroupInfo = ({target}) => {
    setGroupInfo({...groupInfo, [target.name]: target.value})
  }

  // Creating a group
  const createGroup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    const { email, username } = userInfo
    const { groupName, groupPassword } = groupInfo
  
    if (groupName == "") {
      setMessage("Group name cannot be empty.")
    } else if (groupPassword == "" && hasPassword) {
      setMessage("If a group has a password, the password cannot be empty.")
    } else if (groupName.includes("@")) {
      setMessage("\"@\" symbol not allowed in group names.")
    } else {
      setMessage("Loading...")
      // Check if group already exists
      db.collection("things").doc(groupName).get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          setMessage("Group with same name already exists.")
        } else {
          if (hasPassword) {
            db.collection("things").doc(groupName).set({
              name: groupName,
              owner: email,
              people: [username],
              password: groupPassword
            }).then(() => {
              addToUserGroup(email, groupName, groupPassword)
            }).catch((error) => {
              setMessage(error)
            })
          } else {
            db.collection("things").doc(groupName).set({
              name: groupName,
              owner: email,
              people: [username]
            }).then(() => {
              addToUserGroup(email, groupName, groupPassword)
            }).catch((error) => {
              setMessage(error)
            })
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
  const addToUserGroup = (email, groupName, groupPassword) => {
    // Adding the group to the user
    db.collection("things").doc(email).get()
    .then((doc) => {
      let groups = doc.data().groups
      if (groups) {
        db.collection("things").doc(email).set({
          groups: hasPassword ? [...groups, {name: groupName, owner: email, password: groupPassword}] : [...groups, {name: groupName, owner: email}]
        }).then(() => {
          history.push(`/group/${groupName}`)
        })
      } else {
        db.collection("things").doc(email).set({
          groups: hasPassword ? [{name: groupName, owner: email, password: groupPassword}] : [{name: groupName, owner: email}]
        }).then(() => {
          history.push(`/group/${groupName}`)
        })
      }
    })
  }

  const joinGroup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const { groupName, groupPassword } = groupInfo;
    const { username, email } = userInfo

    if (groupName.includes("@")) {
      setMessage("\"@\" symbol not allowed in group names.")
    } else {
      db.collection("things").doc(groupName).get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          setMessage("Group does not exist.")
        } else {
          let correctCredentials = true
          if (doc.data().password) {
            if (doc.data().password != groupPassword) {
              correctCredentials = false
              setMessage("Incorrect password.")
            }
          }
          
          if (correctCredentials) {
            // Check if user in group
            if (username in doc.data().people) {
              setMessage("You are already in this group.")
            } else {
              // Adding the user to the group
              db.collection("things").doc(groupName).set({
                people: [...doc.data().people, username]
              })
              .then(() => {
                // Adding the group to the user
                db.collection("things").doc(email).get()
                .then((doc) => {
                  let groups = doc.data().groups
                  if (groups) {
                    db.collection("things").doc(email).set({
                      groups: hasPassword ? [...groups, {name: groupName, password: groupPassword}] : [...groups, {name: groupName, }]
                    }).then(() => {
                      history.push(`/group/${groupName}`)
                    })
                  } else {
                    db.collection("things").doc(email).set({
                      groups: hasPassword ? [{name: groupName, password: groupPassword}] : [{name: groupName}]
                    }).then(() => {
                      history.push(`/group/${groupName}`)
                    })
                  }
                })
              })
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {
        loading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> :

        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <h1>Username: {userInfo.username}</h1>
          <hr />

          <p>{message}</p>

          <h1>Join Group</h1>
          <form onSubmit={joinGroup}>
            <input type="text" name="groupName" placeholder="Group Name" onChange={changeGroupInfo} style={{width: "200px"}} /><br />
            <input type="password" name="groupPassword" placeholder="Password (Leave empty if none)" onChange={changeGroupInfo} style={{width: "200px"}} />
            <br /><input type="submit" value="Join Group" />
          </form>
          <hr />

          <h1>Create Group</h1>
          <form onSubmit={createGroup}>
            <input type="text" name="groupName" placeholder="Group Name" onChange={changeGroupInfo} /><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="required-password" checked={hasPassword} onChange={changeHasPassword} />
            <label>Has Password</label><br />
            {
              hasPassword && <input type="password" name="groupPassword" placeholder="Password" onChange={changeGroupInfo} />
            }
            <br /><input type="submit" value="Create Group" />
          </form>

          <hr />
          <h1>Already Joined Groups:</h1>
          {
            userInfo.groups ?
            userInfo.groups.map((group) => {
              return(
                <div key={group.name}>
                <Link to={`group/${group.name}`}><h2 style={{display: "inline"}}>{group.name}</h2></Link>
                  {
                    group.owner == userInfo.email && <p style={{display: "inline", marginLeft: "10px"}}>Owner</p>
                  }
                </div>
              )
            })
            : <h1>You haven't joined any groups yet.</h1>
          }

        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Groups
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) returns an `unsubscribe` function, call this in an `useEffect` cleanup function. Since it's a function it can be directly returned from the `useEffect` hook callback to be used when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Checking if user is signed in
  if (!auth.currentUser) {
    history.push("/login")
  }

  // Getting user info
  const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    db.collection("things").doc(user.email).get()
    .then((doc) => {
      let groups = doc.data().groups.length > 0 ? doc.data().groups : undefined
      setInfo({username: user.displayName, email: user.email, groups: groups})
      setLoading(false)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setMessage(error.message)
    })
  });

  return unsubscribe; // <-- return cleanup function
}, []);
```